# Node.js server with daemontools is constantly restarted

Tags: daemon, node.js, daemontools

I want to run a Node.js server with daemontools on Debian (Jessie) but my script running under `supervise` is constantly restarted. This is the run script that I'm using (`/etc/service/node/run`):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec setuidgid nodeuser bash -c './node'
```

The script executes the following script as user `nodeuser`, where I load NVM, change into my code directory, and execute the Node.js server:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Load NVM because we are in a non-interactive shell
export NVM_DIR="/home/nodeuser/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

# Run server
cd /path/to/code
exec node server.js
```

When I start the service with `sudo svc -u /etc/service/node`, the process is restarted all the time and `ps faux` shows the following process hierarchy (the depth of the hierarchy is always changing):

```
/bin/sh /usr/bin/svscanboot /etc/service/
 \_ svscan /etc/service
     \_ supervise node
         \_ /bin/bash ./node
             \_ /bin/bash ./node
                 \_ /bin/bash ./node
                     \_ /bin/bash ./node
                         \_ /bin/bash ./node
                         |   \_ /bin/bash ./node
                         |       \_ /bin/bash ./node
                         |       |   \_ /bin/bash ./node
                         |       |       \_ /bin/bash ./node
                         |       \_ /bin/bash ./node
                         |           \_ tail -n1
                         \_ /bin/bash ./node
                             \_ tail -n1
```

Do you have an idea what's going on there? When I execute the script manually with `./run`, the server starts as expected and shows its output in the console.

**EDIT**

I found out that the service works only after rebooting. Once I restart it with `sudo svc -du /etc/service/node`, it behaves like described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That script is wrong.  The maxim with the daemontools family is that the program executed by `./run` must be the service process *itself*, not its parent, grandparent, or other relative.  Services are run, not spawned.

The use of `exec` on the final line is the right idea, but is ruined by the following use of an explicit `bash -c`.  This is unnecessary anyway, given that the `./node` script has a `#!/bin/bash` script interpreter specified and is (presumably) executable.  Better

```
#!/bin/bash
exec setuidgid nodeuser ./node
```

This can of course be a [`nosh`](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/nosh.html) (from [the eponymous toolset](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/)) or an [`execlineb`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/execlineb.html) script, because there's no real need for the heavyweight Bourne Again shell just to run one single `setuidgid` command.  Thus:

```
#!/bin/nosh
setuidgid nodeuser
./node
```

or

```
#!/command/execlineb -P
s6-setuidgid nodeuser
./node
```

Then when the service manager comes to take the service down in response to `svc -d`, it sends the signal to the correct actual service process.

### Further reading

- himdel (2013-07-24).  [*Deploying node.js with apache & daemontools*](https://himdel.github.io/blog/2013-07-24-deploying-node-js-with-apache-daemontools).  Segmentation fault.
- Steve Kemp (2014-01-04). [*Using runit for maintaining services*](https://debian-administration.org/article/697/Using_runit_for_maintaining_services).  Debian-administration.